# Paypal react native integration

Tags: react-native, paypal

How will you integrate react native app with PayPal. Does react native have any front-end library like react have or how will you add the PayPal functionality to an app. because I googled about that and everyone is saying you have to make a rest api and then connect it to react native app but how?

Comment: Check https://medium.com/@awaisranafastian/react-native-paypal-integration-using-braintree-e356d31e6bad

Comment: Not sure there's a need for the Braintree gateway nowdays; there's a relatively new Native Checkout SDK that may be preferred, https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/in-app/ -- but I haven't made it work with React Native specifically